# How to switch to a dedicated laptop Nvidia graphics card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 21.04, hybrid-graphics

I cannot for the life of me get anything to run on my Geforce.

I am running a laptop on ubuntu 21.04 with an integrated(UHD Graphics 630) and a dedicated GPU(GP107M Geforge GTX 1050 3GB).

I have installed [the latest recommended drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAVMt.png). I have selected [the right card on performance mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwe6e.png). Yet in [the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIYuo.png), I see the wrong card selected, while I can see [the card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjT5k.png)

I can note however that the interface of "NVIDIA X server settings" is lacking a lot, I can only see the "PRIME profiles" tab.

Comment: Did you see any relevant error messages?

Comment: I sadly did not.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot get anything to run on my Geforce'. Since you're aware that the server settings lack certain things the Geforce is apparently working.

Comment: no program will use my Geforce, everything uses the integrated one.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is hybrid graphics and switching between the cards. You can install bumblebee(look info about it) and run you program with optirun command. I don't use ubuntu so i don't know if you have automated switching mode or global switch. Try bumblebee.

Comment: ahh yes let's install a program that hasn't received an update in **8** years